# segmentation fault while passing local array`s element as pass-by-value to another function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void gradescounter(int[], int);

int main(void){
   int indexnum;
   int grade[indexnum];

   /* processing phase */

   printf( "Please enter the index number: ");
   scanf( "%d", &indexnum);

   gradescounter(grade[indexnum], indexnum);
}
```

When I enter the number, I encounter the segmentation fault error. Could somebody tell me where I was wrong? Also, when I used gcc to compile, there is a warning that passing argument 1 of 'gradescounter' makes pointer from integer without a cast, why is it?  Thank you for everyone could help

Answer (score 4):

1. `indexnum` isn't initialized when you use it to create the `grade` array.  You should probably use a known value there instead.
2. You are passing an `int` to a function that expects `int[]` (which is just syntactic sugar for `int *`).  That's the problem - either pass `grade`, or change the function to take just `int`, whichever is correct.
3. `main` should probably have  a `return` statement somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Carl Norum

See the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
void gradescounter(int*, int);

int main(void){

   int indexnum;
   int grade[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

   /* processing phase */

   printf( "Please enter the index number: ");
   scanf( "%d", &indexnum);

   gradescounter(grade, indexnum);

   return 0;
}

void gradescounter(int *array, int index){

    if(index > -1 && index < 9)
        printf("The number entered is : %d\n",array[index]);
else 
        printf("Please enter the index number in the range of 0 and 8\n");    
}
```

Comment: What if the indexnum was 11?

Comment: @ZhiqiangMa it would be some garbage value. 
The function `gradescounter` was not defined so i made a sample example of how he should go about it 
in my example he can check for the index and then print the value in the array :)